# Is spherical geometry "infinite" in the same sense that a Euclidean plane is?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, infinity, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

This seems like a pretty straightforward question (assuming I worded it well), but I've never been able to find an answer anywhere. So, in Euclidean geometry, a plane extends infinitely in all directions, meaning you can have things like

- two points any arbitrary finite distance apart
- infinite plane tilings
- etc

But spherical geometry, in my understanding of it, seems like it wouldn't be infinite in the same way, as going in one direction leads you back to the same place you started. You can imagine an infinite plane but not an infinite sphere. Also, there are some characteristics in spherical geometry that would only work on a finite geometry, such as any property relating to great circles (the existence of a great circle implies there is some "largest" circle, meaning the geometry cannot be infinite).

So (hoping this was worded clearly), would spherical geometry NOT be infinite? (such as, points cannot be any arbitrary distance apart, or there is some maximum distance two points can be apart?)

Comment: When I was at school I wondered the same thing - I even named an infinite sphere a "mousifold" after my sister who I called "mouse".  However such objects cannot exist, as I found out when I asked this question on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21471/can-you-have-a-spherical-plane

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Interesting that it can't be infinite

Comment: Notice that in the question I give an example of an infinite surface with spherical geometry - but the price is that there are isolated points missing.  From the answers given, my understanding is there is some maximal radius, above which you will get these missing points.  Also if you only want to be infinite in one direction, you can just glue together infinitely many pieces of spheres in a line.  Here by piece of sphere I mean the set of points with latitude between $-10^\circ$ and $10^\circ$, and longitude between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$.